# Trying to create a function

Tags: vb.net, function

So I'm trying to change this sub in to a function so that I can reference it and set a label.text as it's result, this is so I don't have to creating new subs to update different labels.

```
Dim drive As String = "C"
        Dim disk As ManagementObject = _
            New ManagementObject _
            ("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""" + drive + ":""")
        disk.Get()
        Dim serial As String = disk("VolumeSerialNumber").ToString()
        Label1.Text = ("Serial: " & serial)
```

Can someone tell me how I can change this in to a function? I've tried declaring Serial as an empty String and then changing the last line to read:

`Return serial = disk("VolumeSerialNumber").ToString()`

At the moment this just sets Label1.Text to display "False", like I've set it as a Boolean or something?!

I'm learning functions at the moment, I'm trying to make things cleaner as up until now I've just been creating different subs to update labels etc...

I'm looking for some tips so I can try and get this myself.

Comment: can you show the whole function - include the declaration/signature/header.  it is incomplete as it is to be a function

Comment: btw could you adjust the formatting as well?

Comment: You say `change this sub in to a function`, where is the sub that you are trying to change? What you have is called "code", the difference is that subs have parameters. While it is possible to guess what you are trying to do, it's best to eliminate guess work at the early stage (before we give you an advice that won't fit your need). Please add more detail about **what** you are trying to do, **not how** you are trying to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really a simple refactoring operation.

```
Sub Main

    Dim driveLetter = "X"
    Try
        Dim result = DriveSerialNumber(driveLetter)
        Console.WriteLine(result)
    Catch ex as Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error: drive " & driveLetter & ": " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Public Function DriveSerialNumber(drive as String) As String
    Dim disk As ManagementObject = _
            New ManagementObject _
            ("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""" + drive + ":""")
    disk.Get()
    return disk("VolumeSerialNumber").ToString()
End Function
```

However, be prepared to receive Exceptions if you pass an invalid drive letter

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I didn't realize I hard to declare it as a string within the first line.